# How to model a satellite MLI blanket? (as a mesh)

Tags: modeling, mesh, cloth-simulation

I am trying to model a satellite MLI blanket, like these ones:

[image]

I have to say that I am not interested at all about the colour, or the glossiness, only the geometry. I am really trying to obtain a correct mesh.

***EDIT:*** Thanks to @Duarte Farrajota Ramos, here is my new attempt. First I tried to work on the same mesh:

[image]

Then, inside the *Cloth* modifier, I have chosen the *Silk* preset, have put Pressure to 0.1, added my Group to the *Pin Group* inside the Shape submenu, where I have set the *Shrinking Factor* to -0.12. Still, there is an absolutely perfect symmetry on the object, which I am trying to avoid. I don't know how to avoid that, or what I am missing, as @Duarte Farrajota Ramos in his answer succeeded to obtain something more "random":

[image]

***NB:*** For information, here is my Modifier menu:

[image]

Comment: I don’t think you want pressure, I think you want the pins to pull in a bit so the fabric has just a tiny bit of slack that adds wrinkles.

Comment: Have a look at sculpting with cloth simlation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5J5os8P4jg

Comment: @TheLabCat How can I do that? I tried but didn't get a correct result. I cannot use sculpting, because I will need to automate the method using Python's Blender API after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Make your mesh high poly enough, that there is enough detail for the cloth simulation to operate on, but low enough that you can still model your shapes confortably. Subdivide after the fact with a *Subdiv* modifier if necessary.

Your topology should also be more or less uniform. Avoid faces with large size differences, prefer quad dominant topology, and make faces approximately square shape in aspect ratio.

[image]

Select all edges, borders and zones where the MLI blanket is attached or fitting tightly around the hard surface underneath it, and add it to a new vertex group.

[image]

Add a cloth simulation to the object. Turn on *Pressure* under *Physical Properties*, and add a value anywhere around 10 to 20, depending on your mesh density. Under *Shape* add the previously created vertex group to the *Pin Group* property.

The key factor is now to use a negative *Shrink Factor* with a low value of around $-0.01$ to $-0.05$. You may  also want to lower or entirely disable *Gravity* under *Field Weights.*

[image]

These values will vary depending on the size, density of your mesh topology and level of subdivision, adjust to you specific case.

[image]

To get bigger coarser wrinkles, use a lower detail mesh with sparser subdivision.

Comment: This is really excellent, thank you. My only problem is that my rendering is symmetrical (I've put a picture on my first post), but yours looks more random. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Probably cause by wrong modifier order, no? You might have a *Mirror* modifier after the simulation, rather than before.

Comment: This is something else.. I haven't used a Mirror modifier.